# Getting credentials in a SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE app. with those methods in the security config file:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(publicMatchers()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/calzadas/list")
                .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .eraseCredentials(false)
                .userDetailsService(userSecurityService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

and here my LoginController

```
@Controller
public class LoginController extends ICryptsController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    /** The login view name */
    public static final String LOGIN_VIEW_NAME = "login/login";

    @RequestMapping(value={ "/", "/login"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String login() {     
        return serverContextPath + "/" + LOGIN_VIEW_NAME;
    }
}
```

but I don't now from where to extract the credentials of the user in plain text (user / pwd)

Comment: You can retrieve the currently authenticated principal is via a static call to the SecurityContextHolder or in controller, you can get Authentication object via a method argument.
More details in [here](https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the credentials from method arguments in your controller class. For example. Since you gave a success url, you can do this.

```java
@Controller
public class LoginController extends ICryptsController {
   ...
   @RequestMapping(value={ "/calzadas/list"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
      public void list(Authentication auth) {     
         Object credentials = auth.getCredentials();
   }
```

This is just one way, there are many examples on the internet.